# SQL Linked Server Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, linked-server, openquery

I have 2 different SQL databases "IM" and "TR". These have different schemas.

- IM has the table "BAL" which has 2 columns "Account"  and "Balance".
- TR has the table "POS" which has 2 columns "AccountId" and "Position".

Here the common link is  BAL.Account=POS.AccountId.

The POS table has > 100k records. BAL has few only records as it shows only accounts which are new.

I want to run a select query on IM Databases' BAL table as follows:

Database: IM

Select Account, Balance from BAL

However, here the "Balance" should return the results from TR Database POS.Position based on BAL.Account=POS.AccountId

How can I achieve this in the fastest manner by not slowing the databases and considering that this query will be executed by lot of users every now and then. Should I use OPENQUERY? I will use where clause to shorten the return time.

Comment: Are the databases on the same server? Separate servers (linked)?

Comment: Databases are on separate servers which are linked

Comment: Then use a `JOIN` with their fully qualified name... `linkedname.dbname.schema.table`

Comment: OPENQUERY or a direct query against a linked server (`SELECT ... FROM [Server].[Database].[Schema].[Table]`) would work fine. In either case, you will get the best performance with a dynamic SQL statement. That will pass over your filtering criteria (the Account values) to the second server. If you don't do that, frequently the second server will send back **ALL** records, and the filtering will be done on your local server.

Comment: @WEI_DBA - I disagree. There are too many cases I have encountered where the remote DB decides to send all records back to the local DB for filtering. It is much more efficient to have the data filtered on the remote server when you are only returning a small subset of the records involved.

Comment: This is unclear. Maybe in this case we can guess what you mean but you should say it clearly. What does "the common link is BAL.Account=POS.AccountId" mean? What does "based on" mean? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. To describe a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. Or give *some* code for the result you want. [ask] [mcve]